# PHP login validator + store user id

Tags: php, mysql

I already store the logged username in a $_SESSION[user_name] variable.  How can I additionally store the user_id in the $_SESSION[user_id] variable. I've tried to use $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); but have had no luck.

I have a MySQL table as such:

login:

```
+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    auto_id    |  username   |  password   |   user_id   |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|       0       |      a      |      b      |      1      |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|       1       |      c      |      d      |      2      |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|       2       |      e      |      f      |      3      |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

my php login validator is:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('php/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $username = $_POST['user_name'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $user_id_col = "3";

  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tapp_login WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
  $stmt->store_result();
  if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
  {
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
  $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']=true;
  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
  echo 'true';
    }
  }
  else {
    echo 'false';
  }
  $stmt->close();
}
else{
}
$con->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$stmt->fetch() returs a value, but you never store it in a variable.

Use

```
while($data = $stmt->fetch()) { 
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $data['userid'];
}
```

Comment: I think this exactly what I need. The logic makes perfect sense.  However, when I echo the $_SESSION['user_id'] I get nothing, but if I echo $_SESSION['user_name'] I get the appropriate username. Any other thoughts?

Comment: What does vardump($data) say? Perhaps made a typo or so

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough, place the var_dump($data) within the wile-loop. The second time `$data = $stmt->fetch()` is run fetch will return NULL (no more results).

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$user_id` is never defined in your code. I assume you are using PDO for your querying, this should do the trick

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']=true;
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
```

Since you only expect one result, you don't need a while-loop.

If you wonder about the cryptic `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, you can read about it in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).